# Ggplot Date x-axis correction

Tags: r, datetime, ggplot2

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
                   pollster    enddate rawpoll_clinton rawpoll_trump
4208               EPIC-MRA  1/26/2016            51.2          48.8
4168               EPIC-MRA  3/22/2016            56.0          44.0
4162               EPIC-MRA   8/4/2016            57.3          42.7
1187               EPIC-MRA  9/13/2016            52.1          47.9
747                EPIC-MRA  10/3/2016            57.3          42.7
368                EPIC-MRA 10/24/2016            54.7          45.3
124                EPIC-MRA  11/3/2016            52.5          47.5
3132 Glengariff Group, Inc.  5/26/2016            52.9          47.1
2282 Glengariff Group, Inc.   8/1/2016            56.5          43.5
789  Glengariff Group, Inc.  9/28/2016            54.5          45.5
436  Glengariff Group, Inc. 10/11/2016            58.0          42.0
```

I am trying to make a plot that has a separate line per poll to show how approval changes with time.

The code I used to do this for "clinton" is below:

```
ggplot(data = mich_polls, aes(x = enddate, y = rawpoll_clinton, group=2)) + 
  geom_line(aes(colour = pollster, size = 1.5))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 40, hjust = 1))
```

However, this only produces a graph with messed up date axis that is out of chronological order:

[image]

To solve this, I have tried converting the `enddate` variable to Date format, but end up with strange results. Most attempts produce a list of `NA` values. The following two produced something odd:

```
as.Date(data.frame(as.factor(mich_polls$enddate), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)[[1]], 
                   format = "%d/%m/%Y")
```

which gives:

```
 [1] NA           NA           "2016-04-08" NA           "2016-03-10" NA           "2016-03-11"
 [8] NA           "2016-01-08" NA           "2016-11-10"
```

I have also tried:

```
as.Date(data.frame(as.factor(mich_polls$enddate),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)[[1]], format = "%d/%m/%Y")
```

which gives:

```
[1] "2016-01-26" "2016-03-22" NA           "2016-09-13" NA           "2016-10-24" NA          
 [8] "2016-05-26" NA           "2016-09-28" "2016-10-11"
```

Could anyone suggest how to either fix the data format OR suggest another way to make my line graphs?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly apply `as.Date()` like so:

```
mich_polls$enddate <- as.Date(mich_polls$enddate, format="%m/%d/%y")
```

In the plot use `scale_x_date()` and option `date_breaks` where you can apply values like `"2 weeks"`, `"1 month"` and such kind of stuff; just look into `?scale_x_date`, after loading `library(ggplot2)` of course.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = mich_polls, aes(x = enddate, y = rawpoll_clinton, group=2)) + 
  geom_line(aes(colour = pollster, size = 1.5)) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks="1 month") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 40, hjust = 1))
```

*Yielding:*

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
mich_pols <- structure(list(pollster = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("EPIC-MRA", "Glengariff Group, Inc."
), class = "factor"), enddate = structure(c(18287, 18343, 18478, 
18518, 18538, 18559, 18569, 18408, 18475, 18533, 18546), class = "Date"), 
    rawpoll_clinton = c(51.2, 56, 57.3, 52.1, 57.3, 54.7, 52.5, 
    52.9, 56.5, 54.5, 58), rawpoll_trump = c(48.8, 44, 42.7, 
    47.9, 42.7, 45.3, 47.5, 47.1, 43.5, 45.5, 42)), row.names = c("4208", 
"4168", "4162", "1187", "747", "368", "124", "3132", "2282", 
"789", "436"), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

I had faced a similar issue while handling dates. This is a long method but its simple and works. Try this out:

1.Load the date into a data frame

```
 df = data.frame(Date = (file$enddate)
```

2.Create a new variable and use factor to the Date

```
new_var <- factor(df$Date)
```

3.Use `character.Date`

```
new_var <- as.character.Date(new_var)
```

4.And finally use `as.Date`

```
new_var <- as.Date(new_var,"%d/%m/%Y) #In your case use month date and year
```

5. Append this to your original `dataframe` and plot as usual